# Zsh + tmux + oh-my-zsh: Autocomplete produces remnant characters

Tags: zsh, tmux, oh-my-zsh

I recently installed **Zsh** in hope of a better life and brighter mornings. However, I quickly realized **Zsh** introduces various issues in conjunction with **tmux**.

The first issue was some weird stuff happening at the end of the prompt, before my commands, but this was resolved by supplying **tmux** with the **-u** flag for unicode-support. However, I am stuck with one final issue that needs resolution before I can use **Zsh** with **tmux**:

**Usecase**: *Autocomplete a command which contains multiple suggestions*
**Issue**: *Autocompletion shifts suggestion one character to the right, while leaving the original character behind (visual bug, it is not included in the command)*

### Example 1.

[image: Ex. 1]
Then I hit **TAB**..
[image: Ex. 2]

### Example 2.

[image: Ex. 3]
Then I hit **TAB**..
[image: Ex. 4]

**Note 1:** This does **NOT** occur when using the Bash-shell.
**Note 2:** I am using "oh-my-zsh". This issue only occurs when using the provided themes. This narrows it down to an "oh-my-zsh"-theme issue, not native zsh/tmux.

Comment: Further investigation revealed that the culprit was the "oh-my-zsh" plugin **tmuxinator**. "Tmux autocompletion", should have seen this sooner. Issue resolved.

Comment: Do you have ZSH_TMUX_AUTOSTART="true" in your .zshrc? This is weird because in my case I am also getting your problem when this setting is present. After removing it and manually starting tmux, I no longer get the issue.

Answer (score 5):

In case some people still get a similar issue, see also the top-voted answer of [Remnant characters when tab completing with ZSH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19305291/remnant-characters-when-tab-completing-with-zsh). The plugin you were using may have had the same non-printable characters issue, that would explain the symptoms.