# Different multiline prompt behavior using zsh + oh-my-zsh + iTerm2 + High Sierra

Tags: zsh, iterm2, oh-my-zsh, macos-high-sierra

On the latest macOS High Sierra, iTerm2, zsh, and oh-my-zsh, I've noticed that tab completion when using a multiline prompt is no longer flushing correctly. I've verified this issue on two separate machines and I'm wondering:

1. if you can also verify this is an issue for you
2. how to start zeroing in on which system is causing this issue
3. if you know of a workaround

#### Example prompt:

```
PROMPT="$(virtualenv_info) %n at %~ on %M $(vcs_info)
%(!.#.$) "
```

Which produces:

```
(myvirtualenv) me at ~/source/some-repo on localhost [master]
$
```

#### Issue:

When attempting tab completion for commands like `ls` or `cd`, hitting TAB to see subdirectories causes the subsequent print to overwrite the lines containing the prompt:

```
(myvirtualenv) me at ~/source/some-repo on localhost [master]
$ ls some-f...
```

Hit TAB

```
(myvirtualenv) me at ~/source/some-repo on localhost [master]
$ ls some-folder/
```

Hit TAB again

```
  some-folder/
folder-1/    folder-2/    folder-3/
```

The above output overwrites the lines containing the prompt. I've tried [setting locale info and different kinds of newlines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19305291/remnant-characters-when-tab-completing-with-zsh). This multiline prompt still works correctly on an older version of zsh running on a CentOS AWS box I have, and tomorrow I can confirm whether it's still working on a < 10.13 macOS machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to narrow this down by deduction to the `COMPLETION_WAITING_DOTS` setting, which I've now found corroborated in [this oh-my-zsh issue](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/issues/5765). It appears this code behaves differently in High Sierra, so I'll look into that for a workaround or a possible fix. For now my workaround is removing my `COMPLETION_WAITING_DOTS="true"` setting.